# Как сделать незакрывающееся окно Tkinter Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, окно

Мне нужно сделать окно в Tkinter Python, которое невозможно будет закрыть.
Я попробовал это:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry(f'{root.winfo_screenwidth()}x{root.winfo_screenheight()}')
root.mainloop()
```

**Но данный способ несовершенен, т.к. возможен выход из окна средствами кнопки Пуск, Ctrl+Alt+Delete etc.**
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Типовые сценарии программирования предполагают ходовые вещи, нужные многим. Если вам нужно написать что-то редкое, типа вируса вымогателя денег с незакрываемым окном -- лучше сразу посмотреть в другую сторону.

Comment: Какие нынче ленивые хакеры пошли...

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
def Quit():
    pass
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", Quit)
root.mainloop()
```

В таком случае кнопка закрыть (крестик) игнорируются, так что программу можно закрыть только через  Task Manager

Comment: Спасибо Ahmed Ayman 123! Но как сделать в нём текст?